# Count Zeroes before the Decimal Point

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to count how many zeroes are a before a decimal.

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal x = 0;

            if (Decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out x))
            {
                var y = 1000000;
                var answer = x * y;

                displayLabel2.Text = (x.ToString().Replace(".", "").TrimStart(new Char[] { '0' }) + "00").Substring(0, 2);



            }
            else
            {
                displayLabel2.Text = "error";
            }
        }
```

When I plug in (lets say) 7.2 I get an output that displays 72, which is what I want. Now I need another display. That initial 7.2 is being multiplied by 1000000. So the quotent of that would be 7,200,000.00. Now I need to some how count the 5 zeroes before the decimal point and display 5 for that. Then if I were to do .72. My Quotent would be 720,000.00. And I would need to display 4, for the 4 zeroes. And so on. Then I need to output that number to displayLabel5.Text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one line `Linq` you could try to count zeroes before the decimal.  You can `Split()` first by the decimal then perform a `Where().Count()` to get the number of zeros.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string myString = (720000.00).ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(myString.Split('.')[0].Where(d => d == '0').Count());
    }
}
```

Results:

```
4
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KiGUEO)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty code so be careful, but AFAIK this is *the fastest* way to do it.

```
// Input assuming you've sanitised it
string myInputString = "720000.00";

// Remove the decimals
myInputString = myInputString.Substring(0, myInputString.IndexOf("."));

// The count
int count = 0;

// Loop through and count occurrences
foreach (char c in myInputString) 
{
    if (c == "0")
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Count is now 4.

Guarantee you this is faster than Regex ;-)

**Edit:** Sorry for the multiple edits, it's been a long day. Need coffee.

Answer (score 0):

use a regular expression to find all the zeros before the period, then get the string length of that match.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(0+)\.?");
string value1 = "7,200,000.00";
value1 = value1.Replace(",",""); //get rid of the commas
Match match = regex.Match(value1);
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value.Length);
}
```

As always test the code because I wrote it just now here in this little text box and not in actual visual studio where I could compile and test it myself. But this should at least illustrate the methodology.

**Edit:**
slight tweak to the regex to account for the possibility that the number will not display a decimal point at all.