# startIndex cannot be larger than length of string - Happens while counting zeros

Tags: c#, winforms

```
decimal n = str.Split('.')[0].Substring(2).Where(d => d == '0').Count(s => s == '0');
```

I am trying to make it so I can input code into a text box and count the zeros. Whatever I plug in will be multiplied by 1,000,000. But when input a zero first.

Examples:
0.12
012.0
072
.085

My program will crash and give me this error: "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string." It crashes the second I put in a zero first.

These are what work: 
12.0
850
.82
5.6
etc. as long as it doesn't being with 0. Any fixes?

Here is all my code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (uFCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                nFCheckBox.Checked = false;
                pFCheckBox.Checked = false;
                decimal x = 0;
                if (Decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out x))
                {
                    var y = 1000000;
                    var answer = x * y;

                    displayLabel2.Text = (x.ToString().Replace(".", "").TrimStart(new Char[] { '0' }) + "00").Substring(0, 2);

                    var str = answer.ToString();
                    //decimal n = str.Split('.')[0].Substring(2, str.Length - 2).Count( s => s == '0');
                    //decimal n = str.Split('.')[0].Substring(2, str.Length - 2).Where(d => d == '0').Count(s => s == '0');
                    //decimal n = str.Split('.')[0].Where(d => d == '0').Count(s => s == '0');
                    decimal n = str.Split('.')[0].Substring(2).Where(d => d == '0').Count(s => s == '0');

                   displayLabel5.Text = n.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    displayLabel2.Text = "error";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Ignore the 3 lines commented out, those work the least and cause the most errors

Comment: `"0.12".Split('.')[0] == "0"` You're trying to substring the resulting string at the index 2 but the resulting string is only one character long.

Comment: but if I do str.Split('.'[0] == "0" then I can no longer use substring. Unless I am not understanding what you are saying

Comment: Little side note, not related to your problem, but you can count the occurrences of 0s with this: `str.Count(c => c == '0');`

Comment: But I only want to count the zeros after my main numbers such as 72, 10, 40, 50, are read. not counting the zeroes already in those numbers. Then I also want to count it before the decimal point. If that made any sense

Comment: `"0.12".Split('.')[0]` is an example expression. `"0"` is the resulting string of it. It was an example. Perhaps I should've said "If you split `"0.12"` by `.`, the first item in the array (at index 0) will be everything before the `.` (in this case `0`), and the second item (at index 1) will be everything _after_ the `.` so `12`. You try to substring `"0"` at the index 2 but `"0"` *only has one character*."

Comment: So change my Subtring(2) to substring(0)? When I do that, it doesn't crash. But then it doesn't output properly. Like when I input 50, it is doing 50x1,000,000. Which is 50,000,000. But I only want to count 6 zeros, I dont want to include the 0 in the 50

Comment: May I suggest you revise your program and try to understand what it is actually doing?

Comment: Yeha, ill add breakpoints to it now and see

Comment: This appears to be a build off of your previous questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31149638/count-zeroes-before-the-decimal-point & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167017/how-to-count-zeroes-with-specific-parameters).  Why do you have to do a Substring() after you split the number by the decimal point? Why if your result is 50,000,000 is your result supposed to be 6 and not 7 since there are 7 zeroes before the decimal point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you're trying to get a count of your string, and that count relies on the string being at least 2 characters long.

Since you know if it's 2 characters or less you don't need any zeroes, you can adapt your code like so:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (uFCheckBox.Checked == true)
        {
            nFCheckBox.Checked = false;
            pFCheckBox.Checked = false;
            decimal x = 0;
            if (Decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out x))
            {
                var y = 1000000;
                var answer = x * y;
                displayLabel2.Text = (x.ToString().Replace(".", "").TrimStart(new Char[] { '0' }) + "00").Substring(0, 2);

                var str = answer.ToString();
                //decimal n = str.Split('.')[0].Substring(2, str.Length - 2).Count( s => s == '0');
                //decimal n = str.Split('.')[0].Substring(2, str.Length - 2).Where(d => d == '0').Count(s => s == '0');
                //decimal n = str.Split('.')[0].Where(d => d == '0').Count(s => s == '0');

                string splitString = str.Split('.')[0];
                if(splitString.Length <= 2)
                {
                    displayLabel5.Text = "0";
                }
                else
                {
                    decimal n = str.Split('.')[0].Substring(2).Where(d => d == '0').Count(s => s == '0');

                   displayLabel5.Text = n.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                displayLabel2.Text = "error";
            }
        }
    }
```

This adds the initial check at the beginning that if the length of the string in the textbox is less than or equal to 2, you automatically set your label to 0, otherwise you start your evaluation

Comment: but now it doesn't read if I do "60" as an input and if I do 6.0 it is still counting that decimal which is what I dont want. I see what you are saying though.

Comment: "60" is a main number, which should yield 0 as a result for counting zeros.  How is it counting 6.0? what is the expected result?

Comment: 6.0 x 1,000,000 comes out as 6,000,000. And I dont need it to count the second zero. So it should output 5. Because no matter what I input, the main number and the number following it should never be counted. whether it is 0 or not. Like 0.007. It will be plugged in aand come out to 7,200 so it should display 2, and if it was 70, it will come out to 7,000 and still display 2

Comment: See edits to my code above.  This error is occuring any time you don't have the two leading numebrs.  I've done a check for those leading numbers to make sure they are there, otherwise put 0 in the label (no leading numbers means no zeros).

Comment: This worked exactly how I needed it to. Thank you so much.